# Model is always null when submitting form from Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I have a view called `Currencty.cshtml` and tow methods in my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Currency()
    {
        IEnumerable<Currency> model = unitOfWork.CurrencyRepository.GetAll();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Currency(IEnumerable<Currency> model)
    {
        var test = model;
```

The view itself is :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Currency>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
         <th rowspan="2">Code</th>
         <th rowspan="2">Currency</th>
         <th rowspan="2">Fixing</th>
         <th colspan="2">PayDesk</th>
         <th colspan="2">NoDesk</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <th>Buy</th>
         <th>Sell</th>
         <th>Buy</th>
         <th>Sell</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     { 
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CurrencyID)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.CurrencyName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.FixingRate)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.PayDeskBuy)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.PayDeskSell)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.NoDeskBuy)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.NoDeskSell)</td>
        </tr>
     }
    </tbody>

</table>
    <input type="submit" id="form-submit-button" value="Save" />
}
```

The problem is that I have a breakpoint in `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Currency(IEnumerable<Currency> model)` and I can see that when I submit the form I get there, but the model is always null. Everything seems so straight-forward I just can't see what's going wrong so that I can't get my data back. When I load the form with the `[HttpGet]` method everything is OK and I see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `for` loop and  `indexers` on model:

```
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CurrencyID)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].CurrencyName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].FixingRate)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].PayDeskBuy)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].PayDeskSell)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].NoDeskBuy)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].NoDeskSell)</td>
    }
```

Also in order to apply indexers you should pass List as model. So in your action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Currency()
{
    var model = unitOfWork.CurrencyRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

And in your view:

```
@model List<MyProject.Models.Currency>
```

If you want more detailed information about list binding I recomend you to read these articles:

[Model Binding To A List by Phill Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

[ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries by S. Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Currency>' any idea?

Comment: @Leron, you can always set `Model.ToList()`.

Comment: try return View(model.toList()) in Http Get method

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Not working until change it to `List`. Your example is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Try to bind with `for` loop instead of `foreach`

```
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].CurrencyID)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].CurrencyName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].FixingRate)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].PayDeskBuy)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].PayDeskSell)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].NoDeskBuy)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].NoDeskSell)</td>
    }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not)

Comment: It seams like a trivial thing, yet it's hard to understand where the difference in the two loops comes from. +1 for the reference, which actually sheds some light on why the `for` loop works, and not just a "this works" or "try this" answer.

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Currency>' any idea?

Comment: I couldn't make it work with `IEnumerable`. I'm not sure why - just changing to `List` didn't worked either I had to use both - `List` and `@for()` in order to get it working. In your current example I get an error for using `<` in `i<Model.Count`. I've closed the page with the original error by mistake but it was complaining about using `<` with int and nested... dunno

Answer (score 2):

To be able to list all values of a list of objects and be able to submit all of them to a POST action I faced a strange problem that I always had a null submitted to the POST action. So, I changed the `IEnumerable<>` list on top of the razor view page- this page to `List<>` and I didn't use the `@foreach()`, I instead used the `@for()` with indexing

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].UserId)</td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].UserId)
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].isLead)</td>
    </tr>
    }
```