# Send a list of objects to controller without JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing a form that contains a `List<object>`. This `List<object>` must be sent to the controller but I don't want to use JSON. Is it possible?  Do I have to test with `id="MyField[i]"` or anything like that?

Here is the Razor code that is targeted:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ajout de Critères sur l'audit @Model.idAudit</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        @foreach (var item in Model.criteresList)
        {

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => item.nomCritere, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.nomCritere, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.nomCritere, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => item.libelle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.libelle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.libelle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And the Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Criteres(CritereViewModel model)
        {
            // Call BL to save them all

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: please show us your code. Thanks

Comment: do you send it with form or in http string?

Comment: @teovankot: yes, an object from a form!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 - for loop posts model collection properties but foreach does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not)

Comment: Is the code you posted working? Not sure if you want an alternative  or want this code to work?

Comment: @adiga: not working but they asked me to put code as exmaple so ..

Comment: Okay. Check this article:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) explains everyting about binding arrays in MVC

If you want to post your form values with bare hands you need to do something like this:

```
    @for (var i = 0 ;i < in Model.criteresList.Count();i++)
    {  
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.criteresList[i].nomCritere, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer is viable and what you say also works (`id = "MyField [i]"`) you just have to add the object properties.

```html
@Html.Hidden(string.Format("model.criteresList[{0}].nomCritere", index),someValue)

<select name="model.criteresList[@index].nomCritere" value="someValue">
```

in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Criteres(CritereViewModel model)
{}
```