# How to store the textbox values in database which is created dynamically in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created label  and text box and one add button and save button
  when i click on add button
label and textbox will be added 
and when i click on save button data will added to database and only one name is saving (another dynamic created  textbox values not inserting into database )what i have do enter all the textbox values 
my code is

In model.cs

```
         public void adddata(string Name)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("addvalues", con);       
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }
```

And in controller.cs is

```
 public Action Result Add(database db)
    {
        database objdb = new database();         
        objdb.adddata(db.Name);            
        return View();
    }
```

In the second pic i click on save button only first text box data is enter into database remaining not inserting then what i have to do to enter all text box values
[image: this is my output]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your database class, define "Name" as list,array or any collection type. For example;

```
public class database{
    string[] Names;
}
```

and in view you must create textboxes with the same name, for example

```
<input type="text" name="Names" />
<input type="text" name="Names" />
...
```

MVC will bind them to your model (Mvc is using name conversation to bind data to model)

and controller

```
public ActionResult Add(database db)
{
    database objdb = new database();   

    for(...){
        objdb.adddata(db.Names[i]);  
    }     

    return View();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not

Comment: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b1e0b153-47f4-4b29-8583-958aa22d9284.aspx

Comment: Add dynamic textbox value add in different column in same row.how can save in database pls help me i searched a lot i did not got any where