# What i am doing wrong cause my post parametar is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

can you please tell my what is wrong with my code and what am i doing wrong with my code because my post paramethar is returning  null? 
This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ImeRabota()
{
    var categories = new List<IzberiRabota>();
    foreach (var category in databaseprofil.Rabotas.ToList()) 
    {
        categories.Add(new IzberiRabota
        {
            id = category.Id,
            Ime = category.Ime,
            Assigned = false 
        });
    }
    return View(categories);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImeRabota(List<IzberiRabota> rabota)
{
    return View();
}
```

and this is my html view I don't know what is it:

```
@model IEnumerable<Rabotnik.mk.Models.IzberiRabota>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImeRabota", "Profil", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => product.Assigned)
        @product.Ime;
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
}
```

And this is my ViewModel

```
public class IzberiRabota
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what `IzberiRabota` looks like? Also, have you checked the network tab on the developer tools to see what is being posted?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET look now in the question.

Comment: I believe that the only property being POSTed is the `Assigned` property. I would recommend that you at least add a hidden field inside the for-loop that has the Id, so that it will also be posted. Can you take a look at your browser's developer tools > Network to see what is actually being posted?

Comment: Probably related to using `foreach` instead of a `for` loop.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not