# *Solved* Returning a list with updated model objects from view to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a list with model objects that i send to a view from the controller, see code below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult PlayingQuiz()
{

    string category = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selection");
    Debug.WriteLine(category);


    Parser p = new Parser(category);

    List<Question> quizQuestions = new List<Question>();

    quizQuestions.Clear();

    quizQuestions = p.getQuestionList();


    return View(quizQuestions);
}
```

In the View, a for each loop presents some values from the model objects. **And what i am trying to do is to update the model objects,** and then **return it back to the controller.** So a updated `List<Questions>` with the value `PlayerAnswer` is set, gets to the [HttpsPost] in the controller. See View below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form asp-action="PlayingQuiz">

            @foreach (SuperQuiz1.Models.Question q in Model)
            {
                <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.Question_)</h6>


                <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input asp-for=@q.playersAnswer type="radio" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.correct_answer)> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.correct_answer)
                        <span asp-validation-for=@q.playersAnswer class="text-danger"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input asp-for=@q.playersAnswer type="radio" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.incorrect_answers[1])> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.incorrect_answers[1])
                        <span asp-validation-for=@q.playersAnswer class="text-danger"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input asp-for=@q.playersAnswer type="radio" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.incorrect_answers[3])> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.incorrect_answers[3])
                        <span asp-validation-for=@q.playersAnswer class="text-danger"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input asp-for=@q.playersAnswer type="radio" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.incorrect_answers[5])> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.incorrect_answers[5])
                        <span asp-validation-for=@q.playersAnswer class="text-danger"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>

            }
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit answers" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>



        </form>
    </div>
```

And finally the HttpPost action in the conroller, where i wanna receive the list:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PlayingQuiz(List<Question> updatedQuestions)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
    Debug.WriteLine("SIZE: ", updatedQuestions.Count);
    Debug.WriteLine(updatedQuestions[0].Question_);
    Debug.WriteLine(updatedQuestions[0].playersAnswer);


    return View("TotalScore");
}
```

The problem was that i used a foreach loop and needed o use a for loop instead. Got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not) were i found the solution.

Comment: One of the more common issues. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not) and [this](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: thanks alot Steve, this solved my problem!