# For loop in model view ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can I use a `for` loop to show the model view list? Or do I have to use `foreach`?

If yes, can anyone show me an example please? Thank you.

```
@model IList<TestMVC1.Models.Account>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Accounts List</h2>
@{var student = ViewBag.AccoutList; }
@for (int i = 0; i < student.Count; i++)
{
    <div>@student[i].CounterID</div>
    <div>@student[i].AccountID</div>
    <div>@student[i].AccountName</div>
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item.CounterID</div>
    <div>@item.AccountID</div>
    <div>@item.AccountName</div>
}
```

I want to use it with `for` loop not `foreach` but it's not working! I mean the model not the viewBag

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count ; i++)
{
    <div>@model[i].CounterID</div>
    <div>@model[i].AccountID</div>
    <div>@model[i].AccountName</div>
}
```

Comment: why in `ViewBag` when you have a model? `ViewBag.AccoutList;` where is that misspelled added to ViewBag? and if this is not a part of the question why have it here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC 4 - for loop posts model collection properties but foreach does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165632/asp-net-mvc-4-for-loop-posts-model-collection-properties-but-foreach-does-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the **@model** to define the type of model in top of `view` file.

But if you want to access the data you should use **Model** or **@Model**.

Change the `@model` to `@Model`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count ; i++)
{
    <div>@Model[i].CounterID</div>
    <div>@Model[i].AccountID</div>
    <div>@Model[i].AccountName</div>
}
```

Comment: `IList` is a decendent of `ICollection` which has a `Count` property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=netcore-3.1